# How to replace set in immutableJs

Tags: reactjs, immutable.js

i've these piece of code:

```
export function updated(list, el) {
  const id = list.findIndex(item => item.id === el.id);
  return id < 0 ? list.push(el) : list.set(id, el); // chiedere come
}
```

how can i replace the `list.set(id, el)` without the immutableJS.

i tried to

```
list.id = el 

list = {
 el: id,
}

list[id] = el;
```

all of them are mistakes.

Can you please give me an advice please ?

***Update***

as requested from @code-apprentice

I don't need a different behaviour for the function, i need to delete immutable from a big project. 
Now with

`list.id = el`

```
list = {
 el: id,
}
```

esLint with airbnb config says that is a `no-return-assign for this line`

if i try to `list[id] = el` i receive `no-return-assign for this line` and `no-param-reassign for this line`

Comment: For each of the things that you tried, how are they "mistakes"? What happened and what do you want it to do differently?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will return a new object, in a immutable way.

```
 return id < 0 ? list.concat(el) : {...list, id: el}
```

> **Caveats**
>
> As observed by Code-Apprentice if your object contains children that are reference-types themselves then you should spread then as well, cause the references inside will be maintained

Comment: Note that this is a shallow copy. If `list` contains objects or arrays, the new object only has references to those objects and arrays, not copies of them.

Comment: `push` actually mutates the original array, `concat` will return a new array

Comment: Yeap, if list contains reference types you should spread then as well. Good point @Code-Apprentice

Comment: Even if you spread the children, what about **their** children? It is infeasible to do this manually because the nesting can be arbitrarily deep in general.

Comment: Of course this is interesting to observe but in React, children's immutability isn't that useful, sure can lead to bugs, but unlikely will cause you problems, since most of the time the comparisons will be shallow